# Modify a form in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Application : Spring, JSP

Is it possible to create an editable form in spring mvc + jsp?
We can create a new form by using

```
<sf:form modelAttribute="employee method="POST>
```

But once inputs are saved in database, how an form be provided to user that allow them to modify the inputted values?

Sorry, I don't have an idea how this can be done, so have not posted what I have tried!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are currently adding some sort of empty employee entity or form object to model when you render your form. For example:

```
model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
```

If you want to edit the employee record after you save it, just add that employee instance to the model instead of an empty instance. For example:

```
Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployeeById(employeeId);
model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
```

You would need to create a separate controller method which has ID of the employee you want to edit in path variable or request param to know which employee instance to retrieve and add to the model (the example above assumes that you have some service for that).

Hope this helps, if you need any clarification, just leave a comment and I'll try to update the answer.